# Using knockoutjs and jquery retrieve id value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have used knockout and got these back from my ModelView template ...

I want to get the value of the id and show it in my alert ..

```
$('.my-response').each(function() {
    alert($('id'));
});
```

how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.my-response').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```